# Get time in Data Table By Using System.Type.GetType("System.TimeSpan");

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

I have used a data table and having the following code:

```
DataColumn startTime = new DataColumn("StartTime", System.Type.GetType("System.TimeSpan"));
```

Retriving Inforamtion:

```
row["StartTime"] = item.StartTime.TimeOfDay;
```

But is showing 24 hours time format. But I want 12 hours format. What should I use Instead of "System.TimeSpan"

Comment: You can convert it to string with desire format.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `TimeSpan` represents a *duration*, not a point in time.  If you want to represent a point in time use `DateTime` instead (note that using `typeof` is safer):

```
DataColumn startTime = new DataColumn("StartTime", typeof(DateTime));
```

As far as the *format*, that is determined when the value is *displayed*.  So configure your display layer (form, web page, report, whatever) to shoe the time value in the appropriate format.